# How to obtain the explicit form of Lorentz transformation matrix using Lie algebra?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra

Consider the Minkowski space $\mathbb R^4$ with the Minkowski metric tensor
\begin{align}
\langle,\rangle:\ \mathbb R^4\times\mathbb R^4&\longrightarrow\mathbb R
\\ (u,v)&\longmapsto\langle u,v\rangle=-u_0v_0+u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3=[u]^\top\eta\,[v]
\end{align}
where $\eta=$ diag$(-1,I_3)$.

We know that the Lorentz transformation is represented by a matrix $L\in GL_4(\mathbb R)$ such that
$$L^\top\eta\,L=\eta. $$
Each Lorentz transformation is a transformation of space-time coordinates between a stationary inertial frame $(t,x)$ and a moving inertial frame $(t',y)$ in the direction of the velocity $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ with respect to the frame $(t,x)$.

I want to derive the explicit form of $L$. One common approach is decomposing vector $v$ into two terms $v=v_{\perp}+v_{\parallel}$, do some classical algebra and geometry, and then we will get the concrete matrix
\begin{align}
L=\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & -\gamma v
\\ -\gamma[v] & I_3+(\gamma-1)[\widetilde v][\widetilde v]^\top
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
This way is indeed quite simple, but it doesn't satisfy my desire. I interest in the approach using Lie algebra, which may involve more calculate, but it will be a good chance, a first step to get used to dealing with Lie algebra and from there do it proficiently in the next parts of General Relativity. At this time, I don't know much about Lie algebra, I don't know what it's about, I don't know what tool it uses. So I really hope that anyone will guide me.

Comment: It's all in the book by Wu-ki Tung. Due diligence.

Comment: Actually it is much less calculation. Let $\psi$ be the rapidity i.e. $|\vec v|=c\tanh\psi$. Then prove $(\hat{\vec v}\cdot K)^3=\hat{\vec v}\cdot K$, because this immediately produces $e^{\psi\hat{\vec v}\cdot K}=\mathbb I+(\cosh\psi-1)(\text{stuff})+\hat{\vec v}\cdot K\sinh\psi$, and that is very easy to compare with the final answer.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#The_Lie_group_SO+(3,1)) for more info on what naturallyInconsistent is talking about.

Comment: *I don't know what tool it uses.* Matrix exponentiation.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent what is $K$, and what operation is $\cdot$ ?

Comment: Ghoster gave the correct Wikipedia link for what $K$ is, and the dot product should already be in your toolbox.

Comment: Since you seem to have a broad interest in Lie theory, you might be interested to check out the Physics Stack Exchange chat called "hbar" and ask questions there. You can find a hyperlink to the chat on the bottom of this page.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I still yet to know what is the definition of the product $\cdot$ in this case, I don't even know if it is the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^4$ or it is the matrix product or any other kind of product, so it's really hard for me to understand the idea.

Comment: $\hat{\vec v}\cdot K=(v_xK_x+v_yK_y+v_zK_z)/v$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent so $K$ is a vector, not a square matrix ?

Comment: K are matrices. $v_i/v$ are "scalars". The linear combination of matrices still makes sense with the dot product as a suggestive shorthand as to what we are trying to do and mean.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent okay I got that

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent why the matrix $exp(\psi\widehat{v}\cdot K)$ and not the matrix $exp(|v|\widehat{v}\cdot K ) $ ?

Comment: Because the exponential using the magnitude |v| gives the wrong answer. The correct additive parameter in SR is the rapidity $\psi$ not the speed

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I mean from where we know to consider the matrix $exp(\psi\widehat v\cdot K)$, but not another matrix ? I think it comes from the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$, but I don't know how to explicitly explain that. How to deduce for any Lorentz boost $L$, $L$ takes the form $L=exp(\psi\widehat v\cdot K)$ ?

Comment: I do not know how to deduce that. It is easy to show equivalence, injectivity and surjectivity, so I'm not inclined to ask for more. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lie algebra is the linear approximation of the Lie group at the identity
$$L = 1_4 + \epsilon \ l_{ik}$$
where $1_4$ is the 4d identity matrix and $$l_{ik}$$ a linear transformation in the 2d-plane with indices $i,k$
e.g. $l_{0,2}$

$$L=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \ + \  \epsilon \ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 c & 0 & d & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

Now you can simply use

$$\partial_\epsilon\ \left(
   \left( 1_4 + \epsilon \ l_{ik}\right)^T \cdot \eta \cdot \left( 1_4 + \epsilon \ l_{ik}\right) - \eta \right)   |_{\epsilon\to 0}  =0 $$

and

$$\det\left( 1_4 + \epsilon \ l_{ik}\right) =1$$

This last equation, indeed, is the defining equation of the special orthogonal group $(SO(3,1))$, the Lorentz group.

As a Lie group, you can go to the limit of infinite powers

$$\left( 1_4 + \epsilon \ l_{ik} \right)\to \left( 1_4 + \frac{\epsilon}{n} \ l_{ik}\right)^n \to e^{\epsilon \ l_{ik}} $$
to retain the three 1-parameter subgroups of boosts and the three rotation groups in the six 2-planes of $\mathbb R^4$

It needs some analysis of matrix functions, to show that the product limit of powers of $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\ (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n = e^n\ = \ \sum{\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$ is working within a frame of convergencies in norms for matrix operators, and for operators in Hilbert spaces, generally.

The explicit forms are
$$l_{0,1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$
etc with exponential,

$$\exp\left(u\ 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)\right)$$

$$  1_4 + 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) * \sum_0^\infty \ \frac{u^{2n+1}} {(2n+1)!}  
+
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) *\sum_1^\infty \frac{u^{2n}} {2n!} 
=\cosh u \ 1_4 + \sinh u \ l_{0,3}$$

and the same with alternating signs and trigonometric functions for the rotation sungroups

Comment: so Lie algebra is the tangent space of a Lie group at the identity element ?

Comment: By the Lie group identities the tangential space is translation invariant $$T_x(G) =g(x)^T\ T_1 g(x)$$

Comment: I am not sure that this answer really touches on the notion of Lie algebras as OP asks about in their question. The alternative that I have in mind is to start with the Lorentz algebra and use the exponential map to generate the restricted Lorentz group.

Comment: @RolandF so here is my solution : 
I deduced that every $X\in\mathfrak{so}(1,3) $ takes the form $X=\theta\cdot J+v\cdot K$, where $K$ is sum of the matrices $l_{ik}$ as you mentioned, and $\theta,\,v\in\mathbb R^3 $. 

Since the exponential map is bijective from $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)  $ to $SO^+(1,3)$, each Lorentz transformation $L\in SO^+(1,3)$ has the form $L=e^X$ for some $X\in\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$. The general Lorentz boost is obtained when $\theta=0 $, and hence $L=e^{v\cdot K}$. However I have no idea how to deduce that $L=e^{\psi (\widehat v\cdot K) } $ where $\tanh\psi=|v| $.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum:

With the six generators in $$l_{ik}\in so(3,1)$$ of the one-parameter subgroups, it remains to show that the total of $SO(3,1)$ is the exponential of any linear combination of 3 boost parameters and 3 rotation angles
$$L\left((u_{0,1},u_{0,2},u_{0,3}),\ (\phi_{1,2},\phi_{1,3},\phi_{2,3})\right)$$
such that
$$L_{\vec u,\vec \phi} = e^{\vec u\cdot \vec l_t + \vec \phi \cdot \vec l_x}$$
and to show that
$$L_{\vec u,\vec \phi}^T \ \eta \ L_{\vec u,\vec \phi} =  \eta$$
$$\eta L^T \eta = L^{-1} $$

We know from the analoguous analysis of the rotation group SO(3), that its not a simply connected manifold by the fact that rotations of $\pm \pi$ in any 2-plane have to be identified. So a path crossing any greatest circle cannot be shrinked to a point.

SO(3,1) has this feature, too.

$SO(3,1)$ has 3 more components around the matrices of reflection of time and/or on any space 2-plane.

So its no wonder that there exists a single component, simply connected representation of the  $\mathit{so}(3,1)$ algebra.

Namely $\mathit{sl}(2,C)$, the 2d special linear group of matrices with complex combinations of $2\times2$ hermitean, trace 0, Pauli matrices  representing the basis.

The real combinations represent generators of boosts, the imaginary combinations  generate rotations.

Like $SU(2)$ for $SO(3,1)$, the group $SL(2,C)$ represents the most elementary and topological simple representation of the Lorentz group.

At the price, that angles run over $(0,4\pi)$, rotations by $2\pi$ yield a $-\text{identity}$ on the space directions.

This fact eliminates the possibility to find a parity operator in the elementary representation.

The group homomorphism map   $SL(2,C) \to SO(3,1)$  acts by identifying all matrices $L,-L$, rotations by $\phi$ and $\phi +\pi$,  as a double cover of of the $SO(3,1)$-manifold.

An intuitive correct image of the group manifold of the Lorentz group $SO(3,1)$:

Four identical copies of the component around the identity, generated by the two inversions of time and space.

The copy of identity is a   ball of radius $\pi$ with  antipodes on the surface identified is a boost hyperbola, eg in the $(x_1,t)$ . At any point attached as a fiber is sitting a $SU(2)$ . Thats similar to the representation of the unit sphere as a half circle with a circle attached at each point with the radius equal to the distance from its  axis.